# Cant Update TableAdapter in DataSet

Tags: c#, dataset, ms-access-2016, tableadapter

I am using MS Access (2016) and C#. I just add a new column to ms access and I have to update TableAdapter but when I configure the TableAdapter, It shows me error =>

> An expected error has occurred. 
>   Please record the following message
>   when seeking support from Microsoft:
>
> Source: Microsoft.VSDesigner ErrorCode:-1 Additional Info:

[image]

I just already google and I don't see the useful answer. I already created a new TableAdapter for that table and error still occur.

Comment: You need to post the code you're using if you want any help.

Comment: @anustart, Ohh, I thought there is no code changing and All are just configuration changing. Please let me know, which part of the code may affect this error? So I can provide u.